# How can I type hint a dictionary where the key is a specific tuple and the value is known?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, types, python-typing, typeddict

How can I type hint a dictionary where the key is a specific tuple and the value is known?

For example I want to type hint a dict like this:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class_map: = {
    (str,): A
    (int,): B
}

some_cls = class_map[(str,)]
```

The use case will be to go from a known set of bases to a class that was previously defined using those bases.

Comment: Just to clarify, because you are speaking in singular, you mean that dictionary will only have exactly one key-value-pair? And both key and value are exactly known ahead of time? Seems like a strange use of dictionaries. Do you mind explaining the use case?

Comment: No it will have more values, I just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do this by

- making a new class ClassMap which will allow dict key lookup

  - note: dict cannot be subclassed because our `__getitem__` signature differs from the one that dict uses
- in ClassMap define `__getitem__` which gets values from an input dict
- in ClassMap define an overload of `__getitem__` with the tuple input and type hint output
- making an instance of the ClassMap
- use it and type hints work
- passes mypy check

Another thing that we can do is require that the input to make the dict is a frozenset of tuples. Then one can type hint what is allowed in:

```
tuple_items: frozenset[
    typing.Union[
        typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.Literal['1invalid'], int],
        typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.LiteralString, float]
    ]
] = frozenset({
    ('1invalid', 1),
    ('a', 1.234)
})
```

This enables functionality similar to TypedDict but with tuple keys.

```
import typing

class A:
    pass


class B:
    pass


class ClassMap:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.__data = data

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, name: typing.Tuple[typing.Type[str]]) -> typing.Type[A]: ...

    @typing.overload
    def __getitem__(self, name: typing.Tuple[typing.Type[int]]) -> typing.Type[B]: ...

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.__data[name]

class_map = ClassMap({
    (str,): A
    (int,): B
})


some_cls = class_map[(str,)]  # sees A, works!
```

Comment: Having just one `overload` signature does not make much sense. Overloads are used, when a function can have _more than one distinct_ call signature. In this case you can just annotate `__getitem__` accordingly without the overload since you only have one signature. Also, I am afraid this is in no way similar to `TypedDict`. This is just a class with a `__getitem__` method that restricts the key and value types.

Comment: There are more overloads in my real life case. I think that it is similar to TypedDict in that we have a known key and a known value and want to know the value type given a known key.